# AWS::S3::NoSuchKey The specified key does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3

I am trying to serve part of website from S3 (`mydomain.com/frontend-beta`).

I created bucket with name `frontend-beta` and enabled static web hosting with all necessary permissions. Also able to access http://frontend-beta.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com with out any error.

When I update nginx config from where main website (`mydomain.com`) is served and try to access `mydomain.com/frontend-beta` I get following error

```
404 Not Found
Code: NoSuchKey
Message: The specified key does not exist.
Key: frontend-beta/index.html
RequestId: 6A36E8E8DF29FBCC
HostId: SW2qCgYnhwHtXcDtD8saTIBV6YuExZ8dSZzZPedAYtagyVTq3O00BHAXAotknuF4rRUDJ1xeQYo=
```

in fact bucket/file does exist (`frontend-beta/index.html`), but don't know why its not able to access it.

here is my nginx config

```
http {
      upstream frontend-beta {
          server frontend-beta.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com;
      }
}
server {
        .
        .
        .

        location /frontend-beta/ {
           proxy_pass http://frontend-beta;
    }

}
```

Anyone know whats I am missing here ?

Comment: `Key: frontend-beta/index.html` is not bucket + file in this error -- that's *just* the file, with its path *inside* the bucket.  Nginx isn't removing that first prefix from the matched `location`.  Your config needs to be written to strip that.  You're confused because it happens to be the same string as your bucket name.

Answer (score 0):

Look at log file your key is wrong, so probably some redirection goes to index.html :

```
Key: frontend-beta/index.html
```

your key should match what is object name in S3