# The specified key does not exist - Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to create a temporary URL for a file in my application. I'm able to upload the file to S3 bucket and I'm able to use the method `\Storage::temporaryUrl($this->url, now()->addHour(1))` generating the following URL

```
https://xxxxxx.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/https%3A//xxxxxxx.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/images/fYr20cgYh3nAwoEEQCOTaVTLLo7nRFrXjp7cYcCz.jpg?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAVHH6TLEV3Z2FBWLY%2F20210622%2Feu-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210622T191649Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Signature=6300aa81e69c6f4c96cb6f319a2b5ed2bfc2b2767138994928a49f3f93906745
```

When I click on this URL I get the following error:

```
The specified key does not exist.
```

From this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/28654035/4581336 I have checked the following:

- the file name exists in my bucket and it is a copy-paste of the file under the `Object URL` in my bucket
- I tried removing the extension from the file to see if it affects the URL but no luck as well. Having `xxxx.jpg` vs `xxxxx` as the file name is the same

[image: file name from my bucket]

I'm a fairly new guy in the AWS world so I will copy-paste things that I think might be important to help solve the issue.

The `IAM` user created has the following permissions:

- AmazonS3FullAccess

The bucket `Block Public Access settings for this account` has everything blocked:

[image: Block Public Access settings for this account]

My bucket public permission has everything enabled as well:

[image: my bucket permissions]

I'm currently logged in as a root user (which therefore I'm assuming I can do whatever I want since I'm the root)

If I do all my buckets public I'm able to access the files using the extracted URL generated by the `temporaryUrl` method

## The final goal

The objective of the bucket is to have a place to store files that are uploaded by users in my application. I don't want to have all the files public so I would like to restrict users to the files they own so I create a temporary URL with

```
Storage::disk('s3')->temporaryUrl($url, now()->addMinutes(30));
```

Since I'm fairly new to storing files in S3 my logic may be flawed. Please, correct me if this is not how it's supposed to go.

## Questions I have looked at but didn't help me

- [Amazon S3 exception: "The specified key does not exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653249/amazon-s3-exception-the-specified-key-does-not-exist)
- [CloudFront + S3 Website: "The specified key does not exist" when an implicit index document should be displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060394/cloudfront-s3-website-the-specified-key-does-not-exist-when-an-implicit-ind)
- [aws-sdk: NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44611467/aws-sdk-nosuchkey-the-specified-key-does-not-exist)
- [NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist AWS S3 Codebuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63720820/nosuchkey-the-specified-key-does-not-exist-aws-s3-codebuild)
- [AWS::S3::NoSuchKey The specified key does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53752047/awss3nosuchkey-the-specified-key-does-not-exist)

Comment: As I can see the file url contain AWS bucket url twice, which should appear only once. The problem is with the url / file path you're passing to the temporaryUrl method, which includes the AWS bucket url already. You should pass only the path of the file without the bucket url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first URL, it seems like you've got the hostname there twice - `https://xxxxxx.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com` appears once, and then a second time encoded. Are you storing the full hostname in the `$url` parameter to `temporaryUrl`? You should only be passing the key (the actual filename) to that method.

The error doesn't sound like a permission error - it appears as though you have access to the bucket but just aren't getting the file path correct.

Comment: It was exactly that. Thank you